# UNIQUE function does not filter values

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

```
=arrayformula(UNIQUE(
{
IFERROR(FILTER('New Bets'!A3:H,'New Bets'!I3:I<>""),{"","","","","","","",""})
;
IFERROR(FILTER(Alertas!A2:H101,Alertas!I2:I101<>""),{"","","","","","","",""})
}))
```

[image]

```
=UNIQUE(A3:H)
```

[image]

When I use Unique separately from the rest of the formula, it correctly returns only one row with data, without duplicates. But when using inside the formula, it returns two equal values.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sv1B1mYrhpzS-ZtCLfLkVPtbffWq231woEX_qOxiAXA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 I had forgotten, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(
 {IFERROR(FILTER('New Bets'!A3:H,'New Bets'!I3:I<>""),{"","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(FILTER(Alertas!A2:H101,Alertas!I2:I101<>""),{"","","","","","","",""})})))
```

[image: 0]